# How can users like and unlike each others post using postgres nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Im very new to this and I want to implement that users can delete their like in a post when the request is made and a like has been already created. I can create the like but i cant delete it.

this is my likes model:

```
const Likes = db.define('likes', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            key: 'id',
            model: Users
        }
    },
    postId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            key: 'id',
            model: Posts
        }
    }
})
```

My posts model:

```
const Posts = db.define('posts', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId : {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            key: 'id',
            model: Users
        }
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len: [1, Infinity]
        }
    },
   

})
```

My users model:

```
const Users = db.define('users' ,{
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len: [2, 50]
        }
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            len : [2, 50]
        }
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        },
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    gender: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    birthday: {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
    },
    nickName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    profileImg: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
            isUrl: true
        }
    },
    role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: 'normal'
    },
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: 'active'
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
})
```

This is how im doing the request:

```
const createLike = async (obj) => {

    const like = await Likes.findOne({
        where: {
            userId: obj.userId,
            postId: obj.postId
        }
    })

    if(like){
        await like.destroy()
    }
    
    const data = await Likes.create({
        id: uuid.v4(),
        userId: obj.userId,
        postId: obj.postId
    })
    return data
}
```

After this im able to create the like but not delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you look for a like. If you find it, you remove it and then recreate it again. It should probably be If you find it, remove it, otherwise create it. So:

```
    if(like){
        await like.destroy()
    } else {
        await Likes.create({
            id: uuid.v4(),
            userId: obj.userId,
            postId: obj.postId
        })
    }
```